# insert into table with no value

Tags: mysql

I have a table which only has two column:

```
+------------------+-------------+----------------------------+
|  user_id         |  INT        |  AUTO_INCREMENT            |
+------------------+-------------+----------------------------+
|  user_timestamp  |  TIMESTAMP  | DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  |
+------------------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

Now I am quite confused how will I build my `INSERT` since all the values has default. I have this but seems not working `$query = "INSERT INTO tt_users (user_id) VALUES ()";`. I just want MySQL to insert a new `user_id` which I will retrieve using `lastInsertID`. Pardon, this is my first time doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tt_users (user_id) VALUES (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not insert the user_id.. that one is generated automatically. that's why you have AUTO_INCREMENT .. you can only insert timestamp, and even that is optional since you do have a default value assigned...

Comment: That's why I asked this question.

Comment: There's no rule that says you can't specify the value of a column if it's an auto incremented field. The auto increment only kicks in when you don't have a value specified.

Comment: how is this an answer to the question ?